# How to save JSON values in a variable/array after subscribe?

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript

I'm receiving JSON files that look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpu6p.png):

```
{streetAddress: "Kosterlijand 20", postalCode: "3980", city: "Bunnik", country: "Netherlands"}
```

The files have different length but the structure will always be

```
{key: "string value", key: "string value", etc...}
```

I'm trying to subscribe to get that data, but no matter how I try to subscribe, I cannot store the data in any way. If I only use this:

```
this.service.getEntityDetails()
        .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

I can see in the console:

```
{streetAddress: "Kosterlijand 20", postalCode: "3980", city: "Bunnik", country: "Netherlands"}
```

But if I try anything else, for example this:

```
    public test: any[];
    public test1: any[]=[];
    public test2: string[];
    public test3: string[]=[];
    public test4: {};

    constructor(service:Service){}
    this.service.getEntityDetails()
    .subscribe(data => {
        test=data;
        test1=data;
        test2=data;
        test3=data;
        test4=data;

        console.log("test:"+test+", test1: "+test1+", test2: "+test2+", test3: "+test3);
    });
 }
```

The output in console is always the same:

```
test:[object Object], test1: [object Object], test2: [object Object], test3: [object Object] test4[object Object]
```

I would like to make it work the way `KeyValuePipe` works.

But because I cannot save these values in any way, I cannot use the pipe. Can someone help me solve this?

I can provide more information if necessary.

Comment: @SuyashGupta Why should he? Unless he uses a version below Angular 5, there is NO need to map it to a json format.

Comment: Of course it will be always [object Object] because you try to output the object. That's not how console.log works in tandem with strings. You're a bit confused what happens.

Comment: `console.log("test:"+test+"...)` is wrong first off... it should be `console.log("test:", test, "test1", test1...");`

Answer (score 1):

So, to explain a few things...

```
public someRandomData: Array<any> = [];

  this.service.getEntityDetails()
    .subscribe(data => {
        someRandomData=data;
    });
```

That's it. You already successfully stored the value you wanted to get.

If you REALLY wanted to do a console log of your object in a string, you either refer to the fields the object has like...

```
console.log(this.someRandomData[0].fieldOfYourJSONObject)
```

Of you write a function that iterates through the keys of your objects. But since you only asked for storing your object, that should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You could use async pipe instead of subscribing in the ts file.
Using the example of @ak.leimrey and @Fateme Fazli

```
/** @file app.component.ts */ 

@Component({ /* ... */ })
export class AppComponent  {
    public test$: Observable<any[]>;

    constructor(service: Service) {
       this.test$ = this.service.getEntityDetails();
    }
}
```

In your template:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(test$ | async) as test">
    <div *ngFor="let item of test | keyvalue">
        {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I think the user struggles on a very basic level. He's saving the value, but makes the basic mistake, that he doesn't refer to the objects with either their index or fields and thinks they're unreadable based on the way he constructed his console.log statement

Comment: Yes I answered maybe a bit too fast... Thank you !

Comment: No, it's a great response and shows how you can use the keyvalue pipe! The issue simply was "simpler" than that.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to display data that comes from a datasource, it should be stored in a component property. Example:

```
/** @file app.component.ts */ 

@Component({ /* ... */ })
export class AppComponent  {
  public test: any[];

  constructor(service: Service) {
    this.service
      .getEntityDetails()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.test = data;  
        console.log('My data', this.test);
      });
  }
}
```

Then you can display it like this:

```html
<!-- @file app.component.html -->

<div>{{ test }}</div>
```